# Using JavaScript to customly stylize buttons with given data?

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to make a custom button with JavaScript and I don't understand it so well, along with how to give that data to each button, I am not sure what property to use for that. Well I have `Button 1` and I have this script (not anywhere sure if it is correct):

```
function customizeButton(fontColor, backgroundColor) {
    string.fontcolor(fontColor);
    button.style.backgroundColor="backgroundColor";
}
```

How will I hook that information with the button so it is displayed, or will I have to just use CSS?

Comment: Weere does `button` come from? Anyway, it's just a matter of setting `button.style.backgroundColor=backgroundColor` (no quotes!). The same goes to the font color, use `button.style.fontColor = fontColor`.

Comment: I would like to have the function customize each button differently, so one button has the font color as black, another button has the font color as blue, how do I approach this, or is it possible?

Comment: Pass a reference to the button into the function!

Comment: I'm sorry, I just really don't know what property I should use to pass the reference. Value or style, or another one? or should I even use a property?

Comment: I believe that should be `button.style.color`

Comment: @Jeffman You're right, don't know how I could miss that. Added that to my answer. I'll be glad to upvote your answer if you add one too.

Comment: @Shzylo you can give a try to jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, bfavaretto, but there's no point in duplicating. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Most popular way to handle this problem is extending jQuery.

```
$.fn.yourCustomButton = function(caption,fontColor, backGround) {
   ...
   (perform your style using .css() etc 
   or better just add a class .addClass("coolButton") and use the style defined 
   in .css  file)
   ... 
   retun this;
};
```

When it comes to using this, all you need to do is providing a div:

```
<div id="button1"></div>
```

And then bind this div to your function:

```
$("#button1").yourCustomButton("Test Button","#ffffff","#000000");
```

Comment: I don't understand jQuery at all.. I see that jQuery seems to be about the same to js at least. I don't know what `$.fn.yourCustomButton` is, would I specify `yourCustomButton` as my button name? and I have no clue how I would 'bind' the div to the function.

Comment: jQuery is a library with tons of shortcuts to js functionality. (it is still js language)   `$.fn.` is the prefix you use while writing an extension. `$("#button1")` is equivalent to 'document.getElementById('button1')'. You may consider investing some time on jQuery, it pays to do so. These are toy examples in which you code a little less. check out http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `element.style.propertyName`. And if you want to apply that to multiple buttons, make the function take the button as a parameter:

```
function customizeButton(button, fontColor, backgroundColor) {
    button.style.color = fontColor;
    button.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}

var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

customizeButton(button1, 'green', 'red');
customizeButton(button2, 'red', 'green');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPs5m/1

Comment: For anyone who wants to know the basics, the nice thing about this function is it works for _any_ button (or almost any other element, too. The button reference is not hard-coded into the function.

Comment: That is strange, I put it onto my build and it doesn't do a thing, in a direct copy-paste but yet it shows up on your jsfiddle thing. I put it in the `<script>` tags. Even trying to access an outside script document isn't working, what would I be doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably trying to access the buttons (the `getElementById` part) before they exist. Add your `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML, right before `</body>`.